Area 51 account disappeared
I tried to login to Area 51 after a long hiatus and got:

Unable to log in:
No user found

I also notice it's now missing from my list of Stack Exchange accounts.
Instead, my Area 51 account is linked to a non-existent network profile.

Your profile itself still exists. Somehow it got de-linked from your network account - that profile doesn't list any of your other site profiles like it normally does.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for finding it! I still can't login, so I assume someone at SO will have to relink this.

Did you go through account merge since August 2023? (your "last seen" on Area51)

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda Not that I know of. I've had these accounts for a bunch of years. The last time I did a password change was long before 2023.

Odd, hopefully staff will take a look soon and solve it.
